# Uploading file using service object (apiclient.discovery)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

Can I upload file to Google Cloud Storage using service object? Example:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.objects().insert(
    bucket='MY_BUCKET',
    name='test.jpg',
    body={'contentType': self.request.POST.get('image').type},
    media_body=self.request.POST.get('image')
)
response = request.execute()
```

It throws error:

HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/MY_BUCKET/o?alt=json&name=test.jpg returned "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with /upload/">

Can I pass missing path and parameter to discovery.build?

Comment: The value for media_body must be either a string or a MediaUpload. Check out https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload